# Convert into frequency table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I have a table something like :

```
> dt <- data.frame(C1 = c("one", "two", "one"), C2 = c("one", "two", "two"))
> dt
   C1  C2
1 one one
2 two two
3 one two
```

Now I need this table from above:

```
> dt <- data.frame(var = c("one", "two"), C1 = c(2, 1), C2 = c(1, 2))
> dt
  var C1 C2
1 one  2  1
2 two  1  2
```

I have tried various things/functions but unable to get the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option using `tidyverse` would be to `gather` into 'long' format, get the `count` and `spread` it back to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(dt, key, val) %>%
      count(key, val) %>%
      spread(key, n)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  val      C1    C2
#* <chr> <int> <int>
#1 one       2     1
#2 two       1     2
```

If we are interested only in the frequency, then use `summarise_all` with `tabulate`

```
dt %>%
    summarise_all(funs(list(tabulate(.)))) %>% 
    unnest
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sapply(dt, table)
```

Answer (score 3):

Also another solution below:
    1. melting the data using reshape lib
    2. creating table and transposing (as melting puts variable var in front)

```
> dt <- data.frame(C1 = c("one", "two", "one"), C2 = c("one", "two", "two"))
> dt

   C1  C2
1 one one
2 two two
3 one two

> library(reshape)
> t(table(melt(dt, measure.vars = c("C2", "C1"))))

     variable
value C2 C1
  one  1  2
  two  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses base `R` and that will work when some of the factors in the table are not present in every column.

```
> dt <- data.frame(C1 = c("one", "two", "one", "one"), C2 = c("one", "two", "two", "three"))
> dt
   C1    C2
1 one   one
2 two   two
3 one   two
4 one three
> globalLevels <- as.character(unique(unlist(dt)))
> as.data.frame(lapply(dt, function(x) summary(factor(x, globalLevels))))
      C1 C2
one    3  1
two    1  2
three  0  1
```